# Cython optimization slow

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am trying to optimize the following python code with cython:

```
from cython cimport boundscheck, wraparound

@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
def cython_color2gray(numpy.ndarray[numpy.uint8_t, ndim=3] image):
    cdef int x,y,z
    cdef double z_val, grey
    for x in range(len(image)):
        for y in range(len(image[x])):
            grey = 0
            for z in range(len(image[x][y])):
                if z == 0:
                    z_val = image[x][y][0] * 0.21
                    grey += z_val
                elif z == 1:
                    z_val = image[x][y][1] * 0.07
                    grey += z_val
                elif z == 2:
                    z_val = image[x][y][2] * 0.72
                    grey += z_val
            image[x][y][0] = grey
            image[x][y][1] = grey
            image[x][y][2] = grey
    return image
```

However, when checking if everything is as optimized as it should be, I receive the following yellow lines (see picture). Is there anything else I can do to optimize this cython code and make it run faster?

[Output cython file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo97x.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some key points:

- The `len()` function is a Python function and has measurable overhead. Since `image` is an `np.ndarray` anyway, prefer the `.shape` attribute to get the number of elements in each dimension.
- Consider using `image[i, j, k]` instead of `image[i][j][k]` for element access.
- Prefer [typed memoryviews](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html), since the syntax is cleaner and they are faster. For instance, the equivalent memoryview of `numpy.ndarray[T, ndim=3]` is `T[:, :, :]`, where `T` denotes the type of the data elements. If you know that your array's memory layout is [C-contiguous](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#brief-recap-on-c-fortran-and-strided-memory-layouts), you can specify the layout by using `T[:, :, ::1]`. In C, `unsigned char` is the smallest unsigned integer type with 8 bits width (on most modern platforms) and thus equivalent to `np.uint8_t`. Therefore, your `numpy.ndarray[numpy.uint8_t, ndim=3] image` becomes `unsigned char[:, :, ::1] image`, given that `image`'s data is C-contiguous. Alternatively, you could use `uint8_t[:, :, ::1]` after `cimport`ing the C type `uint8_t` from `libc.stdint`.
- The variable `grey` is a double while the elements of `image` are `np.uint8` (equivalent to unsigned char). So when doing `image[i,j,k]=grey` in Python, `grey` gets casted to an unsigned char, i.e. the decimal digits are cut off. In Cython, you have to do the cast manually.
- After you know your code works as expected, you can further accelerate it with directives for the Cython compiler, e.g. deactivating the bounds checks and negative indices (wraparound). Note that these are decorators that need to be imported.

And your code snippet becomes:

```
from cython cimport boundscheck, wraparound

@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
def cython_color2gray(unsigned char[:, :, ::1] image):
    cdef int x,y,z
    cdef double z_val, grey
    for x in range(image.shape[0]):
        for y in range(image.shape[1]):
            grey = 0
            for z in range(image.shape[2]):
                if z == 0:
                    z_val = image[x, y, 0] * 0.21
                    grey += z_val
                elif z == 1:
                    z_val = image[x, y, 1] * 0.07
                    grey += z_val
                elif z == 2:
                    z_val = image[x, y, 2] * 0.72
                    grey += z_val
            image[x, y, :] = <unsigned char> grey
    return image
```

Looking closely, you'll see that there's no need for the most inner loop:

```
from cython cimport boundscheck, wraparound

@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
def cython_color2gray(unsigned char[:, :, ::1] image):
    cdef int x, y
    for x in range(image.shape[0]):
        for y in range(image.shape[1]):
            image[x, y, :] = <unsigned char>(image[x,y,0]*0.21 + image[x,y,1]*0.07 + image[x,y,2] * 0.72)
    return image
```

Going one step further, you can try to accelerate Cython's generated C code by enabling your C compiler's auto-vectorization (in the sense of SIMD). For gcc/clang you can use the flags `-O3` and `-march=native`. For MSVC it's `/O2` and `/arch:AVX2` (assuming your machine supports AVX2). If you're working inside a jupyter notebook, you can pass C compiler flags via the `-c=YOURFLAG` argument for the Cython magic, i.e.

```
%%cython -a -f -c=-O3 -c=-march=native
# your cython code here..
```

Comment: Could you please explain the third point, about using unsigned char instead of numpy.ndarray[numpy.uint8_t, ndim=3]? Will this be preferred on any dimension? Are there equivalents to other types? For example, something to use instead of arrays of np.int's

Comment: @Burno The third point suggests to use [typed memorviews](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) instead of np.ndarrays, since the syntax is cleaner and they are faster. As to the `unsigned char`, it's just the equivalent C data type to `np.uint8_t`, i.e. it's an unsigned integer type with 8 bit width (on most modern platforms). Note that you could also use the C type `uint8_t` from stdint.h, which is also available in Cython, see [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libc/stdint.pxd).